# Google Sheets problem with IF(AND()) formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula:

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(LEN(IMPORTRANGE("https://my_table_url";"ЗАКАЗ ОБРАЗЦОВ!R16:R")); IMPORTRANGE("https://my_table_url";"ЗАКАЗ ОБРАЗЦОВ!U16:U") = "НН"); IMPORTRANGE("https://my_table_url";"ЗАКАЗ ОБРАЗЦОВ!B16:B"); ""))

When R16:R is not empty and U16:U = "НН" сolumn B16:B must be filled, but it's only works for one cell

(IFS didnt work here, because functions IF, AND, LEN i need to use in russian language, so IFS dont have russian language analogue, only like "IF(AND())"

How can I fix the formula so that it expands to the entire column? ChatGPT and Google search didnt help me...(
StackOverFlow my last hope :)

Im trying this formula from above.
And tried change conditions by priority, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AND and ARRAYFORMULA don't work together, but you should be able to use logic operators by multiplying the conditions:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(IMPORTRANGE("https://my_table_url";"ЗАКАЗ ОБРАЗЦОВ!R16:R")) *  (IMPORTRANGE("https://my_table_url";"ЗАКАЗ ОБРАЗЦОВ!U16:U") = "НН"); IMPORTRANGE("https://my_table_url";"ЗАКАЗ ОБРАЗЦОВ!B16:B"); ""))
```

If it doesn't you can try with MAP:

```
=MAP(IMPORTRANGE("https://my_table_url";"ЗАКАЗ ОБРАЗЦОВ!R16:R");IMPORTRANGE("https://my_table_url";"ЗАКАЗ ОБРАЗЦОВ!U16:U");IMPORTRANGE("https://my_table_url";"ЗАКАЗ ОБРАЗЦОВ!B16:B");
LAMBDA(rval;uval;bval;IF(AND(LEN(rval); uval = "НН"); bval; "")))
```

Comment: Yeeeah, first solution is working now!) Thank you very much!)